# Edit PDF page labels in pdf-tools?

Tags: pdf, pdf-tools

**Q:** how can I change PDF page *labels* with `pdf-tools`?

`pdf-tools` has the capacity to annotate PDFs, which is great.
Can it also change the page *labels* as well?  That is, not the
raw page number, but the labeled page number?

#### Use Case

I scan a lot of books and articles.  I would like to be able to
jump to the page numbers as enumerated in the books/articles, not
just the nominal page number of the PDF.

Example: if I scan an article that ranges from pages 11-20, I want
to be able to embed the pages 11-20 so that I can tell `pdf-tools`
to jump to, say, page label 12, rather than have to use the
nominal page numbers (in this case, PDF page 2 which would
correspond to page label 12).

#### What I Found

A quick `apropos` search turns up `pdf-info-pagelabels`,
`pdf-view-current-pagelabel`, and `pdf-view-goto-label`.  None of
these appear to allow me to edit the page labels.

#### Alternatives Welcome

In the event that `pdf-tools` does not have this capability, I'd
be glad to know of (linux) command line tools that allow me to
edit page labels, as I'm sure I could rig up something with the
right tool.

Comment: the pdftk program provides options for dumping metadata, i.e. `pdftk input.pdf dump_data`, and adding new metadata, `pdftk in.pdf update_info in.info output out.pdf`, so that might be a way to accomplish this. I don't see anything in pdf-tools or the poppler library that it uses that supports this

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the Java variant of pdftk, starting from version 3.1.0.

First, create a file with the metadata you want, e.g.:

```
PageLabelBegin
PageLabelNewIndex: 1
PageLabelStart: 1
PageLabelPrefix: Cover
PageLabelNumStyle: NoNumber
PageLabelBegin
PageLabelNewIndex: 2
PageLabelStart: 1
PageLabelPrefix: Back Cover
PageLabelNumStyle: NoNumber
PageLabelBegin
PageLabelNewIndex: 3
PageLabelStart: 1
PageLabelNumStyle: LowercaseRomanNumerals
PageLabelBegin
PageLabelNewIndex: 27
PageLabelStart: 1
PageLabelNumStyle: DecimalArabicNumerals
```

Then apply it to the PDF file:

```
pdftk book.pdf update_info metadata.txt output book-with-metadata.pdf
```